# ADB recognizes one phone but not another

Tags: android

I have two identical *Moto Droids*. Both are up to date (2.2). I have been using one of the phones for development for some time. I now want to install my app to the other phone but cannot get adb to recognize it.

**Platform**: WinSvr2008R2

- Eclipse with android pluig ins.
- **USB debugging**: **on**.
- Have verified both phones have the same options and settings.
- The phone that is not recognized shows up in Windows Devices.

*Is there some kind of hidden binding that prevents adb from working with mulitple devices?*

Comment: Is the issue that the the apk gets automatically pushed to one device when pressing Run from Eclipse? Are both devices connected at the same time?

Comment: Only one device is connected at any one time. App debugging is turned on. When I run adb devices phone #1 it is recognized fine. When phone #2 is connected adb devices does not detect it. Phone #1 works fine from Run and Debug in Eclipse. Phone #2 does not appear as an attached device in Eclipse. It has been awhile since I set up the first phone. I'm thinking there is a step where the phone has to be registered with adb but can't find the instructions anywhere. My memory may be faulty on this.